# Is there a total alternative to the `read` function?

Tags: haskell, casting, functional-programming

Why does the function `read` terminate the executable when it cannot parse its argument?

It seems to me that it would be more convenient to have a function of type `String -> Maybe a`, which returns `Nothing` if the string couldn't be parsed to the type `a`, but I can't find anything like it. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know much Haskell, but I cannot understand how a `read` function can be pure: by definition it has *significant* side effects.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `read` doesn't read from input; it merely converts its argument to a `String` (like the Python `__str__` method).

Comment: It's one of several functions in the Prelude (including `head` and `tail`) that could have been made total, but were defined as partial functions for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Why do you think that parsing a string requires significant side effects?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Are you possibly confusing `read` with `getLine`?

Comment: @chepner Nitpick: I think you are describing `show` rather than `read`, which goes in the opposite direction. Still the general point stands: `read` converts from a `String` to some type, but does not perform any input/output.

Comment: Bah, I am. `s/to/from/`, and ignore the Python reference.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The function you are looking for is called `readMaybe` and is defined in the module `Text.Read`:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe

It is available since GHC 7.6. Before that you had to call `reads`, which returns a (potentially empty) list of parsed values, and pattern match on it.

Comment: Adding `readMaybe` to the Prelude [cam up recently in the libraries mailing list](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2016-December/027496.html).